# How to show the OS for a specific Jenkins slave node?

Tags: jenkins

In our Jenkins setup we have more than 20 nodes and it would help us a lot if they would show what OS each is actually running on. I'm speaking about the build processess sidebar. Is it possible to achieve that (maybe using a plugin)? Can a slave automatically return the platform name actually?

Comment: Your question asks for a (generic) way to "show what OS each is actually running on" yet your comment below specifically asks to show "the OSes in the build processes status sidebar". Can you clarify your question? Is a report with slave name and OS details sufficient? How much detail do you want?

Comment: You are right, I didn't realize I forgot to specify where I want the info to appear.

Answer (score 3):

`<jenkins_url>/computer/` shows os and architecture for each node:

```
[online]    node1   Linux (i386)
[online]    node2   SunOS (sparcv9)
[online]    node3   Linux (amd64)
[online]    node4   Windows Server 2008 R2 (amd64)
[online]    node5   Windows 7 (x86)
```

If you want to distinguish linux distros - jenkins could not distinguish them - you could put distro in node description and/or labels if you need it

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that page, but that's not what I'd like to see. I wanna have the OSes in the build processor status sidebar, including the actual linux versions. It's kinda weird that the slaves aren't able to determine the OS they run on. I mean, Java has even classes for this.

Comment: the only thing I could suggest is to put this info into node name and use labels instead of node names in jobs (if you currently assigning jobs to nodes by node names, you could create labels with old node names, so jobs will continue to work without changes).